# Show that, there exist pair of odd prime $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ s.t. $4k=(p_1-1)(p_2-1)+(p_3-1)(p_4-1)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ be odd primes.

**Problem**

> Can it be shown that
>
> For every $k>1$, there exist at least one pair of $p_1,p_2,p_3$ and $p_4$ such as
>
> $$4k=(p_1-1)(p_2-1)+(p_3-1)(p_4-1)$$

Example

$8=(3-1)(3-1)+(3-1)(3-1)$

$12=(3-1)(3-1)+(3-1)(5-1)$

Check up to thousand. For greater $k$ pairs get more and more.

```
for(u=1,1000,forprime(p=3,50,forprime(q=p,50,forprime(r=3,50, forprime(s=r,50,if((p-1)*(q-1)+(r-1)*(s-1)==u,print([u,p,q,r,s])))))))
```

I haven't worked hard on the problem above, just tried to make problem like Goldbach's conjecture and easy to solve (maybe) and help to understand Goldbach's. Thanks in advance for your suggestions and answer.

*Related post*

[Not the sum of two relatively prime composite numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/q/354215/149083)

Comment: Your pairs are quadruples though

Comment: If $k$ is prime we may take $(p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4)=(3,3,5,k)$.

Comment: If Goldbach is true, we may take $p_1=p_3=3$ and $p_2+p_4=2k$ (which implies that we know this to work for very many $k$)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, I think you mean $p_2+p_4=2k+2$.

Comment: - since the RHS expression always is of the type 4k